# Programmatically access android photos details

Tags: android, html, photo

I am trying to create a website optimalized for Android where will be an option to take a picture using the phone camera. I would like to add some details to the picture - like maybe link on the website the user went and used the camera from, so he can find it easily in the future. I hope it makes sense.

Do you know if this is possible somehow? Is is possible to code within website? I have done some research but found no information.

Comment: Are you trying to access camera inside the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

According to android this is not possible with in the browser. Because its more like a security breach in the android system. May be the future version of android provide this functionality but as far Jelly beans it doesn't have such function.

If you have looked in [Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com/)

they have diffrent api to access camera inside the webview